# How can I install Invoke package for Python 3.11?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following command: pip install invoke to install invoke to my Python (current version Python 3.11.4).
It gives the following error message:
[image: Error screenshot]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Tried using conda install invoke, the same problem.

Comment: Please post all of the errors as well-formatted text, not an image. Images can't be searched and they can't be read by people using assistive technology.

Comment: it says `"Successfully installed invoke-2.2.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you happen to run `invoke` from the top-level directory of the `invoke` package, and Python doesn't allow the current working directory to be considered a package. For a relative import to work it has to be done from a sub-directory of a package, so in this case you simply have to change your current working directory to somewhere outside the package and `invoke` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  the current directory has the tasks.py file.  I thought that you have to run it in the same folder which contains taks.py.